# Discord.js not sending messages (no errors)

Tags: discord.js

I've just started using discord.js to make a bot to my discord server. I'm trying to make the bot to send a message but it just doesn't do it. I don't even get any errors.
Here's a clip of the code that doesn't work:

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel

    if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
        // User Joins a voice channel
        console.log("Join");

        if(newMember = manu) {
            console.log("kyllä")
            bot.on('message', msg => {
                msg.channel.send("Manu, oletko käynyt parturissa? \n Kirjoita vastauksesi numero. \n 1. Olen \n 2. En");
            })

            bot.on('message', msg => {
                if(msg.content === "2") {
                msg.channel.send("Ja parturin kautta takasin");
                }
                else if(msg.content === "1") {
                    msg.channel.send("Hyvvö");
                }
                else {
                    msg.channel.send("Puhu suomea");
                }
            })
        }
    }
        else if(newUserChannel === undefined){
        // User leaves a voice channel
        console.log("Leave");
    }
})
```

If you can understand the language in the text sections please notice this bot is just for fun :D.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's better to use message collectors than listeners in condition... I think it won't work

Comment: i know its late but instead of doing bot.on use a message collector

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `if(newMember = manu) {`. You need to use `===` or `==` to compare two values. Use `=` only to assign a value to a variable.

Comment: Do you have errors now? Or an other comportment than before?

Comment: I can't see any changes. There is no errors and there wasn't earlier. Earlier I tried to make console log for the if statement and it worked. But for some reason the bot doesn't send the messages on discord.

Comment: It is variable for discord ID and I've checked that it works.

Comment: Use fake value to test like `if(newMember === "YOURID")`

Comment: Nothing changed. The code should detect when someone joins a voice channel (which it does) then check if the joined user is the specific user and if so it would ask on text channel a question and then perform actions according to the answer. I tried using `console.log("It works")` for the user recognition part. It logged it so it worked. It just doesn't send the messages to the discord. Everything else seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is: You put a bot.on in a bot.on. What you can do is put the second bot.on with messages underneath the other bot.on, and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `bot.on('message', msg)`, you should use `bot.on('messageCreate', msg)`